Gondolo-Gelmini change of variables integration bounds
In this article (Cosmic abundances of stable particles: Improved analysis, P. Gondolo and G. Gelmini, Nucl. Phys. B 360 (1991), p. 145-179,) Gelmini and Gondolo makes the change of variables from $(E_{1,2},\cos\theta)$ to $(E_\pm, s)$ by $E_\pm=E_1\pm E_2$ and $s=(p_1 + p_2)^2 = 2m^2 + 2E_1E_2 - 2|\vec{p_1}||\vec{p_2}|\cos\theta$. The integration bounds run from $E_{1,2}\in[m,\infty]$ and $\cos\theta\in[-1,1]$. With the order of integration as $\int ds\int dE_+\int dE_-$ I was able to find $s\in[4m^2, \infty]$.
In this post, the integration bounds for $E_-$ is given.
However, I am still struggling to figure out the boundaries for the $E_+$ integral. I know it should be $E_+\in[\sqrt{s},\infty]$, but I don't know how it is derived.
Any response would be of great help!
